# The mystery of positivity

Tags: phrase-request

I wish to mention a function which is greater than 0 at small arguments. I thought it must be easy, but then came upon a puzzling fact:

I have googled "is positive at small" and received 90 hits
 "is positive at the beginning" - 70 hits;
 "initially is positive" - 40; 
"which is  positive at first" - 3; 
"which is  initially positive" - 42;
"which initially is positive" - 6;

So, what is a common way to say that f(x)>0, when x is small?

Comment: If you mean "f(x) > 0 when x is small", *initially/beginning* may not be a good option. I don't know if x and f(x) are just placeholders or it's written so in your formula. If they are placeholders (for some longer texts), I'd like to suggest using the real texts in the question. Otherwise, "f(x) > 0 when x is small" is good enough already, IMHO.

Comment: If you check the actual references for the hits that you referred to, you may find that many of them relate to the meanings **hopeful** or **favourable** rather than the meaning **greater than zero**.

Comment: "which is initially greater than zero" gives no hits at all :(

Comment: @Damkerng, so there's no decent way to verbalize the first part?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "the first part". If you meant "f(x) > 0", you can simply read it the way you normally read "f(x) > 0", e.g., "f of x is greater than zero" or in a rather formal piece of writing, "the value of the function f of x is greater than zero". (This is probably better as a question on its own, BTW.)

Comment: I have googled "is greater than zero for small". 3 hits :(

Comment: @Serguei I didn't expect you to find many results, not because I thought it was incorrect, but chiefly because I wouldn't write it myself either. If I were to write it, I would write it like this: "f(x) > 0 for |x| < ε", which is much more concise and more clear, mathematically speaking.

Comment: The whole problem arose from my intention to make the text as "non-mathematized" as possible (presumably it is easier to read words than formulas). But now it is already a matter of principle: I can't believe there is no cliche for such a common expression

Answer (score 1):

[*Small numbers* is an idiomatic phrase](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrongLawofSmallNumbers.html), and the usual way to use it in longer phrases seems to be "...**for** small numbers"; [it's also idiomatic to say "...for small/large values of X."](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*%20values%20of%20x&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C*%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blarge%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmall%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdifferent%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcorresponding%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bvarious%20values%20of%20x%3B%2Cc0)

For example,

> [Specifically, the difference in RTs (dRT) for right minus left key responses will be positive for small numbers and negative for larger numbers...](https://www.routledgehandbooks.com/doi/10.4324/9780203998045.ch3)

or

> [For small values of L/r, it is doubtful that either either solution gives good results.](https://books.google.com/books?id=lWUmTmsG-MQC&dq=%22for%20small%20values%20of%22&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q=%22for%20small%20values%20of%22&f=false)

or

> [A range of elastic positions forward of the elastic axis is found to lead to instability for small values of *k*.](https://books.google.com/books?id=UwzWCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA341&dq=%22for%20small%20values%20of%22&pg=PA341#v=onepage&q=%22for%20small%20values%20of%22&f=false)

[It is grammatically correct to say "at small numbers", and you will see that used sometimes](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22at%20small%20numbers%22) (but be careful of cases like "we are looking at small numbers of ____", where the *at* isn't being used the same way!), but ["for small numbers" seems to be more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20small%20numbers%2Cat%20small%20numbers&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20small%20numbers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20small%20numbers%3B%2Cc0)

So the best way to phrase it might be "f(x) > 0, **for small values of *x*.**"

Comment: "which is positive  for small values of" gives 5 results too  :(